# Как ведут себя таймеры на больших промежутках в JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Использую ноду и laterjs. Устанавливаю таймеры на события через день и неделю.

Знаю, что либа использует нативный setTimeout(), выставляя очень длинный таймаут, например день = 86 400 сек. и тд.

Что нужно знать про такие таймеры?

Например, тестируя в винде такое приложение(оно постоянно запущено) и отправляя систему в сон, по включению происходят веселые эффекты. Таймеры срабатывают(каждый день), но время слетает.

Answer (score 1):

Таймеры часто грешат, но чаще с коротким интервалом, по поводу долгий таймеров - гарантированно не скажу, зависит от реализации среды, но я бы посоветовал поставить период в минуту, сохранить стартовое время и в таймере проверять окончание. так мы гарантируем, что проблем не будет. Возможно даже будет сохранять значение при перезагрузке страницы.

При старте таймера:

```
начальное_время = (new Date()).getTime();
```

В таймере

```
прошло_времени = (new Date()).getTime() - начальное_время;

if (прошло_времени > 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7) {
    // Прошла неделя
}
```

прошло_времени - количество в милисекундах:

```
прошло_времени / 1000 // в секундах
прошло_времени / (1000 * 60) // в минутах
//и т.д.
```

**UPD:
Убрал из таймера лишний код и добавил условие**

Answer (score 0):

Есть один важный момент - реализация setTimeout 32-х битная, не зависимо от платформы, т.е. ее можно попросить сработать максимум через 2^32 милисекунд (24 суток с чем-то), если попытаться передать большее число, то таймер срабатывает в следующем loop.